# What is the difference of bitmap.getpixels() on RGB565 and ARGB8888

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

What is the difference between the pixels array obtained by using

`bitmap.getpixels(int pixels [],.....)` on

`RGB565` and `ARGB_8888`?

For ARGB_8888, is the 0x00RRGGBB or 0xAARRGGBB in the pixels array?

Answer (score 1):

Please read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config) for more information. Difference of these two methods are the quality and bit precision. The highest quality that you will get is ARGB_8888 since every pixel stored in 4 bytes. Each channel stored with 8 bits and alpha channel is included. 
However in RGB565, each pixel stored in 2 bytes and RGB channels (without alpha) encoded into 5,6 and 5 bits in the RGB order. As documentation say:

> This configuration may be useful when using opaque bitmaps that do not
>   require high color fidelity

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean that for RGB565, each pixel value is converted to hexadecimal, the effective number of bits is 16 bits, and for ARGB8888, the effective number of bits is 32 bits?

Comment: I think we can say that but i don't have deep knowledge about that. More informed people can answer to that.